# How to stream Google Search console into Firebase Analytics into Google Cloud Bigquery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-search-console

From https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/160902664?hl=en

Hi, I have connected my Google Search Console with Firebase Analytics, and Firebase Analytics with Google Cloud Bigquery, after waiting for a few days, I still don't receive anything from Google Search Console, only Firebase Analytics events.

Did I do something wrong, or something is missing? Is it even possible? (And yes I have a bunch of data in Google Search Console)

I'd really love not having to build a pipeline on top of Google Search Console API, and instead use Google Cloud Bigquery.

Thanks a lot for your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

this is not available as described, however, Google just announced a direct export of Search Console data to BigQuery called [Bulk data export.](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2023/02/bulk-data-export)